# Flotr2, color changed on graph, legend does not update

Tags: javascript, flotr2

When I change the color for a line in a graph, the legend does not update with the same color. It stays the same as default color. Is there something I need to do to update the color in the legend to display the same color as the graph?

Both the code and the jsfiddle is the same example.

http://jsfiddle.net/ye0ny57j/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Flotr2 </title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flotr2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="width:840px;height:400px"></div>
    <script>

        var d1 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]], // First data series
                d2 = [],                                // Second data series
                i, graph;

        var container = document.getElementById('container');

        // Generate first data set
        for (i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5) {
            d2.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);
        }

        // Draw Graph
        graph = Flotr.draw(container,
                [{"label": "d1", "lines": {"lineWidth": "1", "color": "#f00"}, "data": d1}, {"label": "d2", "data": d2}], {
                    title: "Flotr2 test",
                    subtitle: "Subtitle",
                    xaxis: {
                        minorTickFreq: 4
                    },
                    grid: {
                        minorVerticalLines: true
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'ne'
                    }
                });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing color of just the line in your code:

`{"label" : "d1","lines" : {"lineWidth" : "1", "color" : "#f00"}, "data" : d1}`

Try to change the color of the data set:

`{"label": "d1", "lines": {"lineWidth": "1"}, "data": d1, "color": "#F00"}`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/ye0ny57j/9/